# Bootstrap looping a rows on an odd col

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap and the content coming in is an xml feed which changes so I may have an odd number or an even number of cols. I'm using col-sm-6 and I'm trying to close the row off for both an odd number and an even number of rows.

This is the code I'm using to close the rows off, but it messes up when it the content is an odd number because the row doesn't get closed at the end.

I've also realised it does extra loops and doesnt print anything because it checks for active and busy, so a counter isn't working right.

What's the best way to do this?

Link: https://psychicboudoir.com/all-readers/

```
    <div class="container home-section padding-top">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2>All Readers</h2>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
<?php

    $psychiclist = simplexml_load_file('https://www.thecircle.com/newcircle/export/agents.asp?user=PsychicBoud');

    foreach ($psychiclist as $psychicinfo):
        $largeimg=$psychicinfo->largeimg;
        $status=$psychicinfo->status;
        $name=$psychicinfo->name;
        $pin=$psychicinfo->pin;
        $text=$psychicinfo->text;
        $cssclass = strtolower($status);
      //  echo "<script>console.log('$p')</script>";
        if ($status == "available" OR $status == "busy") {
        echo "
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class='row row-centered'>
                <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-4'>
                    <img height='100%' width='100%' src='",$largeimg,"'>
                    <p class='status ",$cssclass,"'>",$status,"</p>
                </div>
                <div class='col-sm-8 col-xs-8 text-left'>
                    <p class='name text-left'>",$name,"</p>
                    <p class='pin text-left'>Pin: ",$pin,"</p>
                    <p class='description'>",$text,"</p>
                </div>
            </div>     
        </div> 
        ";}
        $counter++;
                 if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
                 echo '</div><div class="row">';
               }

    endforeach;
?>

</div>
```

Comment: From your description and code snippet I don't understand, why you even need to check if there is odd or even number of rows...

Comment: _“and I'm trying to close the row off”_ - do you have a particular situation in which that would be necessary in the first place? Because having col-sm-6 elements for more than two columns inside a single row element usually doesn’t break things, those just flow into different “rows” all by themselves.

Comment: I've added in my actual code above and I've realised that the counter isnt going to work becuase it's actually doing checking loops too and not printing if the reader isnt active.

Comment: The reason im doing it is because when I dont use rows there are some spaces where it drops down and theres only one on one row. If it can be fixed with css even better and leave out the rows

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div>
        <div>
            <?php $numOfCols= 2;  $rowCount= 0;  $bootstrapColWidth= 12/$numOfCols;?>
            <div class="row">
                <?php foreach ($carts as $cart ) : ?> 
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-<?php echo $bootstrapColWidth; ?>" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>category/parts/<?php echo $cart->id; ?>">
                            <div class="card" style="min-width: 250px;">
                                <img class="card-img-top" style="min-width: 400px; height: 14rem;width: 100%; top: 0;bottom: 0; margin: auto; position: relative;" src="assets/uploads/<?=$cart->image?>" alt="Card image cap" >
                                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                                    <h3 class="card-title">
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>category/parts/<?php echo $cart->id; ?>"><?= $cart->cart;?></a>
                                    </h3>

                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                        $rowCount++;
                        if($rowCount % $numOfCols == 0) 
                            echo '</div><div class="row">';
                    ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> > this is the best i have got... may u can change it a little to suit u